# SQL joins and a count across three tables

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-tables

I have three tables with the following relevant columns

- Product: ProductID
- Review: ReviewID, ProductID, UserID
- User: UserId, StateID

Not all products have reviews, but all reviews have a product and a user.

I've written a query that returns all product details plus a review count, which is working. Now I want to restrict the review count so it only includes reviews where the user state is 1 (eg not deleted/banned). This is what I have, but it's not quite working

```
SELECT product.*, count(r.ProductId) as reviewCount, u.state
FROM Product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Review r ON p.id = r.ProductId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users u ON u.userId = r.userId AND u.state IN (1)
GROUP BY p.id
```

The count still includes reviews where the user state is 2. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? I'm obviously not that flash at SQL.

The working SQL that does the count is this

```
SELECT product.*, count(r.ProductId) as reviewCount
FROM Product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Review r ON p.id = r.ProductId
GROUP BY p.id
```

Here's the DDL for some sample tables. It creates three cars (car1, car2, car3), adds three reviews for car1 and one for car2, but one of the users who did a review for car2 has a state of 1 (ie ignore):

```
create database products;
use products;
CREATE TABLE Product (ProductID int(10)  AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(20),     primary key(ProductID));
CREATE TABLE Review (ReviewID int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT, ProductID int(10), UserID int(10), score int(10), primary key(ReviewID));
CREATE TABLE User (UserId int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT, StateID int(10), name varchar(20), primary key(UserId));
insert into product values (1, 'car1'), (2, 'car2'), (3, 'car3');
insert into review values (1, 1, 1, 10), (2, 1, 2, 5), (3, 1, 3, 7), (4, 2, 1, 5);
insert into user values (1, 2, 'bob'), (2, 2, 'fred'), (3, 1, 'inactive');
// NB: three reviews of car 1, one by an inactive user. One review of car two by active user.
```

So the result should be:

```
ProductID    name    reviewCount
        1    car1              2
        2    car2              1
        3    car3              0
```

Comment: Count (or rather SUM) something different.

Comment: Strawberry - I tried both SUM and COUNT on p.id and r.id and it made no difference.

Comment: Where did headphone_id come from?

Comment: Sorry that's one of my other tables. I made the example generic to try to make it easier. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query below does not work because you left join to users, which means if the relevent user is in state 2 you will still see their review, just with nulls for the relevant fields from user (presumably you see u.state is null for the rows where the user was in state 2)

```
SELECT product.*, count(r.ProductId) as reviewCount, u.state
FROM Product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Review r ON p.id = r.ProductId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users u ON u.userId = r.userId AND u.state IN (1)
GROUP BY p.id
```

You can change your query to remove the predicate on u.state, and replace the COUNT in your query with a SUM of a CASE statement, with the CASE evaluating to 1 for valid user reviews, and 0 for othersm like this:

```
SELECT product.*, SUM(CASE WHEN u.state NOT IN (1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS reviewCount
FROM Product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Review r ON p.id = r.ProductId
LEFT JOIN Users u ON u.userId = r.userId
GROUP BY p.id
```

I've tried that with the test case you provided earlier, having added in a review for car3 from an invalid user, and it worked fine.

Comment: But I still don't get why you are both counting `r.ProductId` and not `r.ReviewId`

Comment: @Kabulan0lak: Good point about counting the ReviewId - have edited answer to take that into account

Comment: I think we're getting closer, but not quite. I added some DDL above to create a database, table, and data, so we have a precise definition to work with. The review count comes out incorrect (shows 1 review for car1, should be 2), and one product with no reviews doesn't show up (car3).

Comment: Tom - when I change the query to match up with your table definitions (you changed some column names), and change the where clause to look for state 2 rather than 1 (you originally said you wanted state 1, but from your insert statements I see that is the state you DO NOT want), I get a reviewcount of 2 for product 1, count of 1 for prod 2, and count of 0 for prod 3. I will edit my answer for your new explanation of the user state you want, but I think it then does what you want.

Comment: You're right! I'm sorry I must have made a typo when I changed it. Thank you, solved! With a bit of time I might even understand why it works! Thanks for the explanation I'll read it in the morning :)

Comment: @mc110 I've tried applying this to my actual schema, instead of the simple example schema, and despite hours of effort I can't make it work. The only difference is the product table is the name of a specific type of product. Without the where clause you suggested above all of the rows in the product table are returned. With the where clause none of the products with the "do not count" state of 1 are returned at all. It's like it's doing a regular table join not a left join. Any thoughts on what could be going wrong? Anything I could try?

Comment: The problem is when a product is only reviewed by invalid users. I'll edit the query to take that into account.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that first thing tomorrow :)

Comment: @mc110 that worked perfectly on my live database, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try it simple

```
SELECT _p.*, count(_r.ProductID) as reviewCount, _u.stat
FROM Product _p 
INNER JOIN Review _r ON _r.ProductID = _p.ProductID
INNER JOIN User  _u ON _u.UserID = _r.UserID AND _u.StateID = 1;  
GROUP BY _p.ProductID
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. When I do it that way some products aren't returned at all.

Answer (score 0):

You want to count reviews. So count `ReviewId`, not `ProductId`. And your `u.state` isn't in a `where` clause. Try this :

```
SELECT p.*, count(r.ReviewId) as reviewCount
FROM Product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Review r ON p.id = r.ProductId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users u ON u.userId = r.userId
WHERE u.state = 1
GROUP BY p.id;
```

**EDIT**

What happens if you try a simple and heavy request like this ? :

```
SELECT ProductId, ProductName, count(ReviewId) as reviewCount
FROM Product p, Review r, User u
WHERE p.ProductId = r.ProductId AND r.UserId = u.UserId AND u.state = 1
GROUP BY p.ProductID;
```

Comment: This doesn't work either :( I've added DDL above so we have a precise table/data to work with. In that example I end up with it telling me I have one review of car1 instead of 2; car2 and car3 don't appear at all.

Comment: As @mc110 said, you want state = 2 NOT state = 1 ! It makes sense now

Comment: Comes back with one result - car1 with a reviewCount of 1. Suspect we need some kind of an outer join as there are no reviews for car3. Thanks for the extra suggestion though. Just FYI I'll pick this up again in about 9 hours (in the morning).

Comment: Not quite - car3 doesn't turn up, probably because there are no reviews. I suspect an outer join would be necessary. Thanks for the effort though :)